# Check has any request input or not in laravel blade in shortest way

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to check data from my URL that it has any parameter or not? 
I used this condition before

```
@if(app('request')->input('type') || app('request')->input('type-2') || app('request')->input('type-3') || ... many more....)
   <-- code here --> 
@endif
```

now it has too many parameters. is there any shortest way to check has any parameter or not? 
like `app('request')->has('input')` this type of shortest way? please help
note: **laravel version 6.19**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Request::hasAny()`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.html#method_hasAny) should solve your problem:

```
@if (request()->hasAny('type', 'type-2', 'type-3'))
```

It checks if any of the given input item keys are present in the current request. You can also use [`Request::has`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.html#method_has) to check if all of the given input item keys are present.

---

To safely check if there's any input in the current request, use [`Request::except()`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.html#method_except):

```
@if (!empty(request()->except('_token', '_method')))
```

Comment: It works. but I want something shorter than this.  because If I add any parameters in Url then I  also have to add the name in the condition. 
just check all. the parameter has or not. so that If I increase or decrease parameters It will not hamper my code. Is there any way like this? do you know?

Comment: Do you want to know if there's any input items present in your request, whatever they may be?

Comment: Then you might use `!empty(request()->except('_token', '_method'))`. This will safely check if the request has any attribute.

Comment: Thanks @dan exactly I need this one